# Exercise 5.2.7 & 8 from Chung Kai Lai's "A course in probability theory"

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{X_{n}\}$ be a sequence of independent r.v.s with distribution functions $\{F_{n}\}$; and $S_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}$. Let $\{b_{n}\}$ be a given sequence of real numbers increasing to $+\infty$.

Suppose that we have

(1) $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{|x|>b_{n}}dF_{j}(x)=o(1)$

(2) $\frac{1}{b_{n}^2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{|x|\leq b_{n}}x^2dF_{j}(x)=o(1)$

If we put $a_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{|x|\leq b_{n}}xdF_{j}(x)$, then
we have

question 5.2.7 for any $\delta >0$, $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{|x|>\delta b_{n}}dF_{j}(x)=o(1)$ and $a_{n}=o(b_{n})$.

I have solved these two question but was stuck in the 5.2.8 stating that
$$\frac{1}{b_{n}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{b_{j}<|x|\leq b_{n}}xdF_{j}(x)=o(1)$$

There is a hint in the book:

Use the first part of Exercise 7 and divide the interval of integration $b_{j}<|x|\leq b_{n}$ into parts of the form $\lambda ^k <|x|< \lambda ^{k+1}$ with $\lambda> 1$, but I cannot find a suitable $\lambda$ here and don't know how to use the result in exercise 7. Could anyone give a clearer explanation? Thanks for any help!